# Laravel REST apis

Tags: arrays, api, android-studio, laravel-8

I am trying to order my laravel apis by id so that i can use it in my android app but each time l do that it changes the structure. My android app is set to accept array list but each time i order it changes to an object

here is my controller

```
<?php

namespace App\Http\Controllers;

use App\News;
use Illuminate\Http\Request;

class NewsController extends Controller
{
    /**
     * Display a listing of the resource.
     *
     * @return \Illuminate\Http\Response
     */
    public function index()
    {
        $allposts = News::paginate() ->sortByDesc('id');

        return response()->json(['newsitemlist' => $allposts], 200);
    }

    /**
     * Show the form for creating a new resource.
     *
     * @return \Illuminate\Http\Response
     */
    public function create()
    {
        //
    }

    /**
     * Store a newly created resource in storage.
     *
     * @param  \Illuminate\Http\Request  $request
     * @return \Illuminate\Http\Response
     */
    public function store(Request $request)
    {
        //
    }

    /**
     * Display the specified resource.
     *
     * @param  int  $id
     * @return \Illuminate\Http\Response
     */
    public function show($id)
    {
        $allposts = News::find($id);
        if (is_null($allposts)) {
            return response()->json(['message' => "News not available"], 404);
        }
        return response()->json(['newsitemlist' => $allposts], 200);
    }

    /**
     * Show the form for editing the specified resource.
     *
     * @param  int  $id
     * @return \Illuminate\Http\Response
     */
    public function edit($id)
    {
        //
    }

    /**
     * Update the specified resource in storage.
     *
     * @param  \Illuminate\Http\Request  $request
     * @param  int  $id
     * @return \Illuminate\Http\Response
     */
    public function update(Request $request, $id)
    {
        //
    }

    /**
     * Remove the specified resource from storage.
     *
     * @param  int  $id
     * @return \Illuminate\Http\Response
     */
    public function destroy($id)
    {
        $allposts = News::find($id)->sortByDesc('id');
        if (is_null($allposts)) {
            return response()->json(['message' => "News not available"], 404);
        }

        $allposts->delete();

        return response()->json(['message' => "News Deleted Succesfully"], 200);
    }
}
```

here is my model

```
<?php

namespace App;

use Illuminate\Database\Eloquent\Model;
use Illuminate\Database\Eloquent\Factories\HasFactory;
use Carbon\Carbon;

class News extends Model
{
    use HasFactory;

    protected $table = "news";

    protected $fillable = [
        'title',
        'image',
        'body'
    ];

    protected $casts = [
      'created_at' => 'datetime:d-m-Y',
      'updated_at' => 'datetime:d-m-Y'
    ];

    protected $appends=['published'];

    public function getPublishedAttribute(){
        
       // return Carbon::createFromTimeStamp(strtotime($this->attributes['created_at']))->diffForHumans();
       return Carbon::createFromTimeStamp(strtotime($this->attributes['created_at']))->diffForHumans();
    }

}
```

this is how it shows before pagination and ordering

```
{
    "newsitemlist": [
        {
            "id": 1,
            "title": "Is Covid-19 Denialism by leaders criminal?",
            "image": "news/April2021/f4hfCmTrelwsY0DoUDDf.jpg",
            "body":
         }
       [
}
```

this is how it shows after odering and pagination

```
{
    "newsitemlist": {
        {
            "id": 1,
            "title": "Is Covid-19 Denialism by leaders criminal?",
            "image": "news/April2021/f4hfCmTrelwsY0DoUDDf.jpg",
            "body":
         }
       }
}
```

Comment: Have you tried `News::orderBy('id', 'desc')->paginate()`?

Comment: It works thank you but still changes the structure is there a way i can get something like {"newsitemlist":[
      {
        "id":"xxx",
        "title":"xxxx"
         "image":
      }
    [

Comment: I managed to get it work by using the get method ``` New::orderBy('id', 'desc')->take(15)->get(); ```